# Fix or disable Stylus preprocessing for Basic/Starter node.js web project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, stylus

I've created both a Basic Express 3 project and a Starter Express 3 project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and I notice that, although the `.styl` file is where I'm supposed to write my styles, there's no syntax support / IntelliSense / coloring.
Web Essentials 2015.1 is installed but doesn't seem to bring anything extra to the table in this regard.

Can I either

- make this Stylus support work out of the box for the templates or
- disable this particular css preprocessing altogether in favor of simple css?

because as it stands now, this is killing productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `.styl` file will break the file watch and will avoid the preprocessor compiling a css file based upon the `.styl` file.

You can now simply use standard css or add e.g. a LESS file instead.

It was a straightforward answer to a straightforward question, but one that might prove useful to someone.